# Order of Operations

Tags: java

I need help with solving my problem of output code. Sorry for the big chunk of code I need help fixing the output for hI. The two input files can be found (soon to be posted)

Please ask if you need what the output looks like or the formula for solving hI ( I can only post two links.).

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class HeatIndex
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {


    String location = "Key West, Florida";
    File fileNameTemp = new File("KeyWestTemp.txt");
    File fileNameHumid = new File("KeyWestHumid.txt");

    Scanner inFileTemp = new Scanner(fileNameTemp);
    Scanner inFileHumid = new Scanner(fileNameHumid);

    String [] month = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "Novermber", "December"};
    int length = month.length;
    double [] temperature = new double[length];
    int [] humidity = new int[length];
    double [] hI = new double[length];


    //INPUT - read in data for temp and humidity from files

    int n = 0; //index value for arrays
    while( inFileTemp.hasNextDouble() )
    {
        temperature[n] = inFileTemp.nextDouble();
        //System.out.println (temperature[n]); //debug statement - uncomment to see values assignned to temperature
        n++;
    }
    inFileTemp.close();


    n = 0; //reset index to 0
    while (inFileHumid.hasNextDouble())
    {
            humidity[n] = inFileHumid.nextInt();
            //System.out.println (humidity[n]);  //debug statement - uncomment to see values assignned to humidity
            n++;
    }
    inFileHumid.close();

    //PROCESSING - calculate Heat Index if needed- see lecture notes for details, formula is incomplete

    double t = 0.0;
    int h = 0;

    for(n = 0; n < hI.length; n++)
    {
        if( temperature[n] >= 80.0  ) //determine if HI should be calculated, complete the condition based on Lecture notes
        {
            t = temperature[n];
            h = humidity[n];

            hI[n] = -42.379 + 2.04901523*t+ 10.1433312*h- 0.22475541*t*h- 0.000683783*(t*t)- 0.005481717* (h*h)+ 0.000122874*(h*h)*t+ 0.000085282*t*(h*h)- 0.000000199*(t*t)*(h*h);
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code?  What is it supposed to do and what does it actually do?

Comment: The problem with the code is it comes out normally but when temperature  goes into above 80 the code freaks out and starts outputting negative numbers I think it's the problem of the order of operations.

Comment: Where is `hI` defined?  I don't see it in your code sample.

Comment: @dg99 Just added it. (sorry I didn't know it was required)

Comment: Just a tip, the sample code you posted should be able to run as a standalone program

Comment: @Wusiji that would be a lot of code to post but I will do it now thanks.

Comment: The text files are out of reach, have to be logged in.

Comment: @FlyingKalamari No, please don't post the entire program.  The code sample is fine.  But you *do* need to include all the *relevant* parts, such as variable definitions.  (As you just did.)

Comment: in your while loop, shouldn't you be checking for integers? 'while(inFileHumid.hasNextInt())'

Comment: What formula is your code supposed to be using to calculate hI? Can you post the url of a picture of the formula?

Comment: @FlightOdyssey [image](http://imgur.com/poiHghh) [formula(scrolldown)](http://www.srh.noaa.gov/images/ffc/pdf/ta_htindx.PDF)

Comment: @BjørnBråthen It doesn't affect the code at all but yes I should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a coding problem at all, it's an issue with the formula. You need to study up on [scientific notation](http://www.chem.tamu.edu/class/fyp/mathrev/mr-scnot.html).

0.000683783 should be 0.00683783 (6.83783x10<sup>-3</sup>)

0.005481717 should be 0.05481717 (-5.481717x10<sup>-2</sup>)

etc.

See [formula](http://www.srh.noaa.gov/images/ffc/pdf/ta_htindx.PDF).

Comment: I'm sorry I thought it was something with the code but thanks for taking the time to make sure everything is right. Have a nice day!